# HibernatePersistence javax.naming.NameNotFoundException thrown with DataSource

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, tomcat7

I am building a Tomcat Servlet application using Hibernate with a jta data source. My persistence.xml has the following content:

```
 <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
     <persistence-unit name="metadata.model" transaction-type="JTA">
     <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
     <jta-data-source>jdbc/BitronixJTADataSource</jta-data-source>

...
</persistence>
```

In my `${web-app}/WebContent/META-INF/Context.xml`, I have the following content:

```
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/BitronixJTADataSource" auth="Container"
           type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="root" password="mysecretpassword"
           driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metadatadb" />
</Context>
```

Right after the application is started, I issue:

```
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("metadata.model");
entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
```

and get a

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/BitronixJTADataSource] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
```

Do you have any idea why this is occuring?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that in the persistence.xml, the `jta-data-source` was supposed to have the `java:comp/env/jdbc/BitronixJTADataSource` value in order for it to be found in the InitialContext.